# AutoHotKey: Making (caps+key) -> special character?

Tags: autohotkey

In Linux, I use xmodmap with the following configuration:

```
clear lock
keycode 66 = Mode_switch

keycode 34 = bracketleft braceleft aring Aring
keycode 47 = semicolon colon oslash Ooblique
keycode 48 = apostrophe quotedbl ae AE


keycode 21 = equal plus
keycode 35 = bracketright braceright
```

How can I do the same in AutoHotKey?

In other words, how can I make (Caps+[certain key]) -> [certain character]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Christian,

Try this as an example for CapsLock + F1:

```
CapsLock & F1::Send, abcdefg
CapsLock & a::Send, Æ ; to send lowercase Æ, CapsLock+Shift+a is uppercase
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.